# How to send a WPF window behind a windows form when clickwd on windows form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am using an MDI Form for my project. It has a Form (WinForm) and a Window (WPF Window) as Children. I opened the Window and then a the Form. The Window always stays above the Form, even though I can click on the Form. The Form never comes to the front.

I tried with :

```
private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Topmost = false;
}

// this method does not satisfy my condition.
```

Comment: If you are not using MVVM then why tag it?

Comment: Sorry about that. You have a soln ?